# Why doesn't Intellisense show VC++ definition of "interface" macro?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, macros, intellisense

Here's a block of code I'm working with:

```cpp
interface ClassFactory : public IClassFactory
{
    // *** IUnknown methods ***

    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR *ppv);
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)();
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)();

    // *** IClassFactory methods ***

    STDMETHOD(CreateInstance)(LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter, REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR *ppvObject);
    STDMETHOD(LockServer)(BOOL fLock);

public:
    ClassFactory();

private:
    ULONG RefCount;
};
```

VS2015 color-codes keywords like "public" and "private" in blue, user-defined types like "ULONG" and "IClassFactory" in teal, macros like "STDMETHOD" and "REFIID" in purple (well, maybe that's "eggplant"). In the case of user-defined types and macros, I can make Intellisense show me the definition by simply floating the cursor over the symbol. Thus, if I put the cursor over the purple symbol "FAR," I see `#define FAR far` in a gray box on my screen.

The symbol "interface" is color-coded in purple, like a macro. Further, I have to include Unknwn.h to use it (leaving Unknwn.h out causes it to be color-coded blue, and marked with an "identifier 'interface' is undefined" error). Drilling down into Unknwn.h (and thence into objbase.h, thence further into combaseapi.h) I find these lines:

```cpp
#define __STRUCT__ struct
#define interface __STRUCT__
```

So, it seems clear that "interface" is a macro, just like FAR. Yet, even though VS2015 color-codes it as such, when I float my cursor over it, I do not get a gray box showing `#define interface __STRUCT__` as I expect. Further, if I right-click on it, the pop-up menu containing the "Peek Definition" and other entries that would let me see the line that defines a macro in context has those entries grayed out.

Why doesn't Intellisense show me the definition of the interface macro?

(BTW, I believe the use of "interface" in the above code-snippet is poor technique, as the "interface" it declares contains a member variable; it probably ought to be "class" instead. I'm just puzzled by the IDE's behavior and hope someone can explain it to me.)

Comment: hmmm, may have something to do with the fact that `interface` is a C# keyword. wonder if there's some confusion in Intellisense's hover-over

Comment: It is just a bug, the EDG front-end has always struggled to keep up with the C++/CX and C++/CLI extensions.  Use connect.microsoft.com to remind them.  Consider using the `__interface` extension keyword to get a compile error.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x may be right: if I don't include Unknwn.h, but add my own `#define interface struct` to my code, the behavior is the same. But, change `interface` to `interfact` and the IDE behaves properly. @Hans Passant, I did as you suggested.

Comment: Either way, its a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft, by e-mail with me, has confirmed this was a bug, but it was fixed as of Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. I downloaded and installed [Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) today and, indeed, the bug goes away. Intellisense now shows the definition of the macro "interface" as declared in Unknwn.h, and will open that file if you click "goto definition" on the right-click menu.